# Not able to login after migrating libvert on-prem boot disk to Google cloud platform using cloud endure migration service

Tags: ssh, authentication, migration, google-compute-engine

I migrated the vm from libvirt to Google Cloud Platform using Cloudendure. The initial sync is complete and is in Data Replication stage from over a week. Once the VM is launched using test mode and try to putty using ssh it throws Connection Refused exited with error code 255.

I tried to log in using my on-premise local machine username and SSH key with putty, As it is told in the Cloudendure documentation that I can log in to the replicated server using same credentials

The firewall rule in GCP and the machine allows port 22 for incoming connections. SSH key is also updated properly in metadata section and saying SSH key is not propagated properly.

I thought there is a problem with my local machine ufw rules and tried turning off firewall and replicated again but no use. Also tried adding SSH rule to ufw allow connections from 0.0.0.0/0 still I'm not able to connect to VM which is replicated and launched in test mode.

Steps tried:
I tried interactive console method where I tried to log in using serial-port, but the problem is it is asking for ID and password. Where I don't have PASSWORD and using only SSH keys to log-into.

Tried using Static IP for an instance. before replicating boot disk I added firewall rule allow SSH from that static-IP then I replicated and tried to login (assuming that it is blocking connection via this IP).

Followed this article to install Linux Guest OS.
Generated SSH key using ssh-keygen -t RSA -C "" in gcloud shell.
I cannot ssh into the Linux environment. Appreciate the help

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64

ANy help would be greatful.

Comment: What does it say on the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)? It sounds like your VM may not have booted successfully, which could mean you are missing drivers / setup necessary for it to run in GCE. If that's the case, hopefully there would be log messages on the console.

Comment: Assuming that the guest environment is partially working, you can add a startup script to the metadata to set a user name and a password, and then reboot as suggested in this [Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/UHBoUED8eDU). Then you can interact with the serial port console. If it didn’t work, you need to use the clone method detailed in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#startup_script) As a best practice, create a snapshot first

Comment: another possibility is that the internal firewall of the instance is not allowing the ssh connection. Thus you can also use the same method of a startup script to modify iptables

Comment: Thanks, everyone tried adding startup Script  to-the metadata and it worked for me. By resetting my network interface and adding SSH rule to ufw I'm now able to SSH into my google instance with my on-prem private key.